# Plot not appearing in my vignette file but running in my console-

Tags: r

The plot is working pretty fine in the console but when i knit it in my vignette file it is throwing an error .
could someone tell me the prob

```
#function which is running fine in console
plot.linreg <- function(x)
{
  data1 <- cbind(x$fitval,x$residu)
  data1 <- as.data.frame(data1)
  names(data1) <- c("fitval","residu")
  p <- ggplot(data1, aes(x=x$fitval, y=x$residu)) + geom_point(shape=1)+labs(x="Fitted values", y="Residuals") + ggtitle("Residuals vs Fitted") + geom_smooth(method = lm)
  print(p)

  sca_resvar <- x$resvar[1,1]
  st <- sqrt(sca_resvar)
  abs_residu <- abs(x$residu)/st
  stadarres <- sqrt(abs_residu)
  data2 <- cbind(x$fitval,stadarres)
  data2 <- as.data.frame(data2)
  names(data2) <- c("fitval","stadarres")
  p2 <- ggplot(data2, aes(x=fitval, y=stadarres)) + geom_point(shape=1)+labs(x="Fitted values", y="|Standardized residuals|") + ggtitle("Scale-Location")
  print(p2)



}
```

code in vignette:

#### Plot funciton

```
linreg_mod <- linreg(Petal.Length~Sepal.Width+Sepal.Length, data=iris)
plot(linreg_mod)
```

error shown:

```
#> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log): 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
```